# Manipulating BIND 9.x Configuration Files with Java

Tags: java, dns, bind, zones

I need to add/delete domain names to BIND 9.x DNS server. That means i need to read/write to zone files. How can I do this operation using Java?

It is possible to read zone files with sftp (JSch) but parsing, appending files is too complex.
Webmin uses perl scripts and perform these operations successfully.
DNSBoss uses Java and perform these operations successfully but it is not open source.

It seems dnsjava is helpful but I am not sure, I need to dig it more.

Do you have an idea for this operation? Any open source libraries, APIs which can be helpful?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2):

I realized there is a patch named [Bind DZL](http://bind-dlz.sourceforge.net/). I should use it and forget about manipulating files.